# show number of posts posted today

Tags: php

I need to display the number of posts that were added TODAY

I found this one that will show number of all posts but I need only last day

```
<?php
$total = wp_count_posts()->publish;
echo 'Total Posts: ' . $total;
?>
```

I've a felling that it's very easy but I coudn't any script that will work :(

Thank You in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) like this:

```
// we get the date for today
$today = getdate();
//we set the variables, i am ignoring sticky posts so they dont get counted
$args = array(
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1, //all posts 
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today["year"],
            'month' => $today["mon"],
            'day'   => $today["mday"],
        ),
    ),
);

//we create the query
$today_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
//the result already has a property with the number of posts returned
$count = $today_posts->post_count;
//show it
echo $count;
```

Comment: kk it wasn't that easy hehe Thank You it's working great:)

Comment: i updated the answer, i added `'posts_per_page' => -1` to display all posts, it can be done with `'nopaging' => true` too

Comment: I figured it by myself using nopaging but Thanks again for your help

Comment: Script work perfect! Any idea how to add +3h from GMT as this work accordign GMT. Thanks

Comment: @Nick I didnt test this but you need figurete out the GMT value first then added a new array like this `array(
            'hour'      => 03,
            'compare'   => '>=',
            ),
        )` where the 3 is the value you found